# Symfony2: Callback Validation Constraint - object properties not found

Tags: validation, symfony

I am using callback validation constraints as defined in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html#the-callback-method) like this:-

```
/**
 * GD\AdminBundle\Entity\Offer
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="offers")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="GD\AdminBundle\Repository\OfferRepository")
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"isDateValid"})
 */
class Offer
{
```

...

```
public function isDateValid(ExecutionContext $context)
    {
        // This code block gets executed but $this->getEndDate() is NULL
        if( $this->getEndDate()->getTimestamp() < $this->getStartDate()->getTimestamp() ){
            $context->addViolation('End Date cannot be less than Start Date.', array(), null);
        }
    }
```

However if I do a var_dump and test, I find that `$this->getEndDate()` is `NULL`

I am creating new Offer instances from the admin using SonataAdminBundle. 
**What am I doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using the correct namespaces.

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
```

Have you got these two?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've figured this out or not.  But I have the exact same validation in my project.  Here's what I have (confirmed to work):

My callback in my entity:
`* @Assert\Callback(methods={{ "CG5\BFG\CoreBundle\Validators\EndDateValidator", "isEndDateValid"}})`

my validator code (separate file):

```
namespace CG5\BFG\CoreBundle\Validators;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;

class EndDateValidator
{
    static public function isEndDateValid($entity, ExecutionContext $context)
    {
        if ($entity->getEndDate() <= $entity->getStartDate())
            $context->addViolationAtSubPath('endDate', 'End Date must be after Start Date', array(), null);
    }
}
```